# How to configure TS to allow imports from CJS to ES modules (node-fetch & Express)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, fetch-api

I am trying to get two libraries to run in one project: `fetch-node`, which is an ES module, and Express, which is CommonJS. The problem is that I have to import `fetch-node` like so:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

but Express requires me to import it like so:

```
const express = require('express')
```

which is not possible with my config, `package.json`: `"type": "module",` and `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "es2016",   
"lib": ["es2019"],    
"module": "Node16",    
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

So when I import Express like described, I get this error:

```
const express = require('express');
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/mnt/c/Users/Johannes/citygmlToGltf/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///mnt/c/Users/Johannes/citygmlToGltf/bin/app.js:15:17
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Node.js v19.1.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What is the trick here? Can I not use these two libraries together in one project?

Comment: Express _doesn't_ require you to use `require`, if you're using ES modules you can `import express from "express"`.

Comment: hmm very interesting! its true - it now works. strange. i had to install the typings tho `npm i --save-dev @types/express`.  Thanks!
but is there a more general answer to my question - i not only have the Problem with express ;)

Comment: Then could you give a [mre] of a problem you _do_ have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was facing did come from the tsconfig. I had to add:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

to be able to use both `require()` and dynamic import like `import * from "asdf"`